# checkmark not shown when selecting a row progammatically on slickGrid

Tags: select, checkbox, slickgrid, checked

I modified the example-checkbox-row-select.html file on the examples to select a row programmatically.
I added a button with the following code:

```
<button id="clickCheckRow" style="position:relative;height:30px">Click Check Rows</button>
```

and

```
$("#clickCheckRow").click(function() {
        let rowIndex = 5;
        selectedRowsIndexes = grid.getSelectedRows();
        selectedRowsIndexes.push(rowIndex); // add row with index 5 to selected rows indexes
        grid.updateRow(rowIndex); // update the row with index 5
        grid.invalidateRow(rowIndex); // tells that row with index 5 has changed
//            grid.invalidateRows();  // this does not work either
        grid.render(); // the invalidated rows should change, but the check mark does not show up
});
```

When I click the button the row gets selected, but the checkbox does not get checked.

## Update:

I still need a duplicate push to selectedRowsIndexes

```
$("#clickCheckRow").click(function() {
      let rowIndex = 5;
      let selectedRowsIndexes = grid.getSelectedRows(); // using let, as suggested
      selectedRowsIndexes.push(rowIndex); // add row index to selected rows
      selectedRowsIndexes.push(rowIndex); // will not work without this duplication
      grid.setSelectedRows(selectedRowsIndexes);
});
```

Comment: I don't think your code will work, you have to call `setSelectedRows()` to advise the grid of these new selections, just playing with the array is not enough, at least I don't thikn so

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but it only works if I push the new rowIndex twice by duplicating the line selectedRowsIndexes.push(rowIndex).

Comment: I think you're still trying to change the array by pointers and you shouldn't, you should add `const` or `let` when you declare your array. You don't need to invalidate the row, at least I never call it in my code. You can try to add a delay with `setTimeout`, I had to use that in some occasion, especially if you use this in combo with `onSelectedRowsChanged` event, adding a delay will make sure it happens after that event.

Comment: I added the let to my selectedRowsIndexes array but I still need to push twice for this to work. Please see update above.

Comment: I assume you didn't try the `setTimeout` delay, but you should give that a try, if that doesn't work then I don't know, you're doing something wrong somewhere but I can't spot it. You should check that the array you use in the `setSelectedRows()` is the correct output, perhaps do a `console.log(selectedRowsIndexes.length)` and see if the length is the expected one. I never had issues with the `setSelectedRows` except for the delay that I sometime need to use

Answer (score 0):

I also posted this answer on https://github.com/6pac/SlickGrid/issues/478
I don't know however if my suggested modification may have unintended consequences.

When selecting a row programmatically (for instance from a click to a button) the associated check box does not get checked. I modified the program "example-checkbox-row-select.html" from the examples folder for my testing. See below:

```
<body>
    <button id="selectRow5" style="position:relative;height:30px">
      select row 5</button>

    <button id="unselectRow5" style="position:relative;height:30px">
      unselect row 5</button>

    <button id="unselectAllRows" style="position:relative;height:30px">
      unselect all rows</button>
```

. . . etc.

```
<script>
var grid;

$("#selectRow5").click(function() {
    let rowIndex = 5; // use row 5 for this example
    let selectedRowsIndexes = grid.getSelectedRows();
    selectedRowsIndexes.push(rowIndex);
    grid.setSelectedRows(selectedRowsIndexes);
});

$("#unselectRow5").click(function() {
    let rowIndex = 5; // use row 5 for this example
    let newSelectedRowsIndexes = [];
    let oldSelectedRowsIndexes = grid.getSelectedRows();
    while (oldSelectedRowsIndexes.length != 0) {
        let indexFound = oldSelectedRowsIndexes.pop();
        if (indexFound != rowIndex) {
            newSelectedRowsIndexes.push(indexFound)
        }
    }
    grid.setSelectedRows(newSelectedRowsIndexes);
});

$("#unselectAllRows").click(function() {
    grid.setSelectedRows([]);
});
</script>
```

1 - Start the program, Click the first button (select row 5). Row 5 gets selected but the checkbox is not checked.  The box shows checked when manually selecting any other row by clicking on their check box.

2 - Start the program, Click the first button twice. The checkbox is cheked on the second click. Click the second button (unselect row 5). The row is unselected but the check mark is not removed. Click any other row. The check mark now is removed.

3 – Start the program. Click the first button twice. The check mark is checked. Click on the second button (unselect row 5). The check mark is not un-checked. Click on the third button (unselect all rows). The check mark is not unchecked. Click on the checkbox of any other row. The check mark on row 5 is unchecked.

SOLUTION:
Modify function handleSelectedRangesChanged(e, ranges) (around line 2683 of slick.grid.js)
comment lines 2703 and 2705. See below:

```
//  if (simpleArrayEquals(previousSelectedRows, selectedRows)) {
        trigger(self.onSelectedRowsChanged, {rows: getSelectedRows()}, e);
//  }
```

Comment: Version 2.4.21 of slickGrid fixes the problem. Many thanks to the developers.

Comment: Note that we have also incorporated the test buttons you used above into the ```example-checkbox-row-select.html```